# Failed to bind to address https://localhost:7090 - The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key

Tags: iis, https, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

We've been trying to fix a developer's machine with all sorts of HTTPS issues running:

- Windows 11
- Visual Studio 2022
- A .NET 7 C# MVC application

When we attempt to start debugging in Visual Studio, it fails on `app.Run()` with the following exception:

```
System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=Failed to bind to address https://localhost:7090.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.<BindAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.<BindAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.<BindAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<BindAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<StartAsync>d__30`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.<StartAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\MyApp\Program.cs:line 78

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.) (The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.)

Inner Exception 2:
NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.
```

We recently reinstalled IIS and Visual Studio to get the IIS Express Development Certificate regenerated on the machine. It was then exported from `Personal->Certificates` and imported into `Trusted Root Certification Authorities->Certificates`.

We also tried using `dotnet dev-certs https` to generate a certificate as well. It does say:

```
A trusted certificate was found: 5DA2.....AFAC - CN=localhost - Valid from 2022-12-09 15:33:53Z to 2023-12-09 15:33:53Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true
```

When we deploy the .NET 7 application and run it through the local IIS, the page loads, but some static content files (like jquery.js and site.css) will error out with ERR_CONNECTION_RESET and sometimes the page will just load forever without timing out.  The Event Viewer reports nothing out of the ordinary.  And everything works fine under HTTP.

Comment: Merely installing the certificate won't help, as you also need to create certificate mapping with port 7090 in Windows HTTP API, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

Comment: There are many reasons for `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` error, You can try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see if there is more detailed error information, if not, you need to debug the cause using [IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210), this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Turns out the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET was due to Symantec Endpoint Protection causing some issues with IIS.  Still haven't figured out the certificate error though.  This is the only dev PC experiencing it.